# Can't display visual in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to create a custom visual in Power Bi using Python script. My data source is from my excel file and it load properly. But whenever I will type my script in the python script editor and execute it, it always giving me the same error of can't display this visual. Anyone who can help me resolve this? 
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAAoR.png)
[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boAPX.png)

Comment: Hi Ressa. Can you show us your script and the error message? In that way we can better answer your question.

Comment: I edited my post and the links will show you my script and error message.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the same problem thanks to frustration. The working solution felt impossible to me as a python coder. I though I was supposed to modify the two automatically generated dataset related comment lines to code by deleting the `\#` from the beginning of those lines.

How my code looks like now and display works as expected:

```
\# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(..       ! keep this line as a comment ! 

dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates(..  \# this line you can run or leave as a comment  

.. my code ..
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens mostly not only because of a connection to a python script but also connections to SQL connector or even just an update from Power Bi. Check the recent changes in Power BI every month to see if any affect your problem. Also, check your transformations and data types. You may be using text instead of the Whole Number for enumerations